# Access - Get latest date if column contains value from another one

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, syntax

I'm having an issue with a VBA function for my query in Access.
I have a table "**tbldata**"

```
Equipment   Last Inspection
420-413     2019-06-15
440-433     2019-06-15
402-483     2019-06-29
420-413     2019-12-12
```

and a query "**qryunpair**"

```
UnpairEquipment
420 
413 
440 
433 
402 
483
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
Equipment Latest Date
420       2019-12-12
413       2019-12-12
440       2019-06-15
433       2019-06-15
402       2019-06-29
483       2019-06-29
```

I've made the following code, but when I ran it, it didn't return any values.
Is there a solution to this?

```
Function typeinspection(Source As String) As String
Dim Rst As Recordset
Dim Rst2 As Recordset
Dim s As String
    s = ""
    Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbldata")
    Set Rst2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryunpair")
    While Not Rst.EOF

        If InStr(Source, Rst2.Fields("UnpairEquipment") > 0) Then _
            s = Rst.Fields("Last Inspection")
        Rst.MoveNext
    Wend

    Set Rst = Nothing
    Set Rst2 = Nothing
    typeinspection = s

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a query that returns your expected results, you can join the table and the query with the use of the operator `LIKE`:

```
SELECT q.UnpairEquipment AS Equipment, MAX([Last Inspection]) AS [Latest Date]
FROM qryunpair AS q INNER JOIN tbldata AS t
ON '-' + t.Equipment + '-' LIKE '*-' +  q.UnpairEquipment + '-*'
GROUP BY q.UnpairEquipment
```

Results:

```
Equipment   Latest Date
402         2019-06-29
413         2019-12-12
420         2019-12-12
433         2019-06-15
440         2019-06-15
483         2019-06-29
```