# Access query - get latest date with criterias

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

I have the following data in a table "tbldata"

```
Equipment Type  Starting date   Ending Date
420-413     T1     2019-06-10     2019-06-15  
402-483     T2     2019-06-14     2019-06-29  
446-439     T4     2019-07-20     2019-07-30  
420-413     T3     2019-12-08     2019-12-12  
428-421     T2     2019-08-01     2019-09-01  
420-413     T2     2019-09-08     2019-10-04
```

I've made a query "qryunpair" to unpair all matches from Equipment resulting in:

```
UnpairEquipment
402
413
420
421
428
439
446
483
```

I'm trying to have the latest date of "Ending Date" for every Type for each equipments.
I have the following code:

```
SELECT
    qryinspection.UnpairEquipment AS Equipment,
    Max(t.[Ending Date]) AS T1,
    Max(t.[Ending Date]) AS T2,
    Max(t.[Ending Date]) AS T3,
    Max(t.[Ending Date]) AS T4
FROM
    qryunpair AS qryinspection,
    tbldata AS t
GROUP BY qryinspection.UnpairEquipment;
```

It's almost what I'm trying to achieve, but it doesn't take into account the type, I get the same date for every equipments/type:

```
 Equipment   T1        T2             T3           T4
 402    2019-06-29  2019-06-29  2019-06-29  2019-06-29
 413    2019-12-12  2019-12-12  2019-12-12  2019-12-12
 420    2019-12-12  2019-12-12  2019-12-12  2019-12-12
 421    2019-09-01  2019-09-01  2019-09-01  2019-09-01
 428    2019-09-01  2019-09-01  2019-09-01  2019-09-01
 439    2019-07-30  2019-07-30  2019-07-30  2019-07-30
 446    2019-07-30  2019-07-30  2019-07-30  2019-07-30
 483    2019-06-29  2019-06-29  2019-06-29  2019-06-29
```

Is there a fix to this?

Comment: Could you make an example for the targeted result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, e.g.:

```
select 
    q.unpairequipment as Equipment, 
    max(iif(t.type='T1',[ending date],null)) as T1,
    max(iif(t.type='T2',[ending date],null)) as T2,
    max(iif(t.type='T3',[ending date],null)) as T3,
    max(iif(t.type='T4',[ending date],null)) as T4
from 
    qryunpair as q inner join tbldata as t on '-' + t.equipment + '-' like '*-' +  q.unpairequipment + '-*'
group by 
    q.unpairequipment
```

The above is based on the [answer provided by @forpas to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59377191/7531598).

Comment: I ran the code and I got the expected result! I didn't know you could use conditional aggregation in a select statement. Thanks!